# Change the SSL ciphers used by Apache2 in Plesk 11.5 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-http-server, parallels, plesk

I want to change the configuration of my Apache2 server so that it accepts the following lines in order to disable weak TLS ciphers and enable perfect forward secrecy.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCompression Off
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+AESGCM EDH+AESGCM EECDH -RC4 EDH -CAMELLIA -SEED !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

However, I am being a bit confused. Plesk 11.5 was preinstalled on the server and is used to manage the Apache2 webserver. I changed the lines in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf
```

and restartet apache by typing

```
service apache2 restart
```

However, sslscan returns the following:

```
phil@phil-desktop:~$ sslscan www.phkr.de | grep Accepted
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  SEED-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  SEED-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
```

So I assume that I have to change the configuration elsewhere?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Creating the file

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/zz050-psa-disable-weak-ssl-ciphers.conf
```

and adding the lines to it did the trick.